# Salesforce - Docusign Preview button on the record page

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, e-signature

We got a DOCUSIGN button to generate a PDF document and send it to the clients for the e-signature but we need the **one-click button to preview** the document without having to go through all the steps (Selecting template -> selecting recipients --> then clicking on preview button). Really appreciate it if someone could provide guidance here.

Answer (score -1):

With DAL/Apex toolkit, there is no API function allowing to preview a document inside a template. However if an envelope was already sent in draft state, built based on this template, you can preview the envelope with the API function "getSenderViewUrl".
If you're interested, please refer to the documentation: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/envelopeservice.html